# Looking for Venn Diagram Maker

Tags: technology-in-education, software

I want a clickable 3-circle Venn diagram (in a box labeled U), where I can shade each region by clicking. I have googled "venn diagram maker free online" and looked at about a dozen of these sites. Many want me to sign in, which should not be necessary. None of the others are what I want.

If I knew how to program websites, maybe I could make my own.

Does anyone know of a site like this?

I want to be able to make lots of diagrams, all in the same style, for teaching, quizzes, and tests. Basically, I just want to be able to click which regions will be shaded (also being able to label the circles would be nice, they usually need to be A, B, C). I'd like two circles on top and one below, because that's how the diagrams are in the text I'm using (discrete math).

[A year or two ago, I was trying to make my own on drawing sites. Those had issues too. On many, the overlapping circles hid each other. On many I could only shade a whole circle. A drawing site that makes this easy would be just as helpful as a dedicated venn-diagram-maker.]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266395/249220

Comment: I should have been looking in a different SE site, I see. However, I might have a steep learning curve figuring out how to use these. I have a 2nd related goal, which would be to randomize which of the diagrams is chosen, within MyOpenMath. I was going to post that question there, but if someone here knows MoM, I would love a tutor...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here's something I made in Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/n44xx78e49) to this effect. While you cannot click the regions themselves to fill them, you can enable or disable the region by clicking the corresponding folder on the left sidebar to fill the regions.

Edit: I forgot that [Actions](https://help.desmos.com/hc/en-us/articles/4407725009165) are a thing on Desmos! I rebuilt it to have clickable regions based off of Michał Miśkiewicz's fantastic work. [Check out the new **clickable** version here.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/58i1abhksx)

Comment: That is *wonderful*! It was very easy for me to modify it. I changed colors, the placement of set C's circle, and the label positions. And I added a U (for the universal set). Here's my modification of your lovely work: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7p0jgbohdb  And, having it here on MESE means that I'll be able to find it if I lose track of it.

Comment: Also, I liked that you used two words - center and middle - it made it easier for me to think. When I'm playing sudoku, I'll say to myself, middle-not-middle. This is better.

Comment: I blogged about this. Cameron, if you want me to use your name in my blog post, let me know. I'm happy to edit that. http://mathmamawrites.blogspot.com/2022/08/technology-woes-and-cheers-venn-diagram.html

Comment: You're very welcome, Sue! I have a lot of fun building stuff in Desmos, so I was happy to do it. Glad you got it sorted out the way you want. It looks great. A name credit would be much appreciated :) Please feel free to reach out if you ever have similar type questions in the future. I'd be happy to help.

Comment: Just for fun, I made my own Desmos diagram to give an example of how to make the regions clickable. I hope you enjoy it. 
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0su2xnamok

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz, sweet! But the functionality I would want (and I'm guessing many others), is to be able to choose as many regions as we want to all be shaded at once. So each region would separately be shaded or not.

Comment: @SueVanHattum I rebuilt it based on what you wanted and the excellent work by Michał Miśkiewicz.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Fantastic work. I rebuilt mine based on what you did.

Comment: Still ovals here.

Comment: And here's the one I couldn't find. I finally stumbled across it. It's in geogebra, not Desmos. https://www.geogebra.org/m/KSuUb2TR?fbclid=IwAR0F0CNQAP4Lf6DsPRc_hGuKu2Y4qdn4TqmK_VkAy6xETenGGPr3o_ESofw

Comment: Aha awesome find @SueVanHattum .

Answer (score 0):

To summarize:

@CameronWilliams' work gave me what I needed to make all the images I wanted. I am using [this on desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7p0jgbohdb) for that purpose.

I used those images to make a randomized problem in MyOpenMath. It's problem #990768, if you'd like to use it. (I'm using it in a quiz.)

And to help students learn more before the quiz, I point them to [this geogebra page](https://www.geogebra.org/m/KSuUb2TR?fbclid=IwAR0F0CNQAP4Lf6DsPRc_hGuKu2Y4qdn4TqmK_VkAy6xETenGGPr3o_ESofw).